# TypeScript: Overwrite instance function in unrelated class

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, jquery-ui, arrow-functions

I have an `Item` Class built like this

```
export class Item {

    element:JQuery<HTMLElement>

    constructor(...) {
        this.element = $("<div >...</div>");
        ...
        this._tooltipUpdate();
        this.element.tooltip({
            items: "div[data-tooltip]",
            content: this.element.attr("data-tooltip"),
            open: this._tooltipUpdate,
            ...
        });

    }

    ...

    public _tooltipUpdate = ():void => {
        this.element.attr(
            "data-tooltip",
            `...`
        );
    };

}
```

Basically, the `Item` Class has an `element` attribute that holds its DOM element.

I now have a different class, `InventoryElement`

```
export class InventoryElement extends MenuElement {

    amount:number;

    constructor(item:Item) {
        super(...)

        this.amount = 0;

        ...

        this.item._tooltipUpdate = () => {
            this.element.attr(
                "data-tooltip",
                `${this.amount}`
            );
        }
    }
}
```

---

The `Item` instance of `InventoryElement` should have a different `_tooltipUpdate` function, basically.
Currently, it's not overwriting it correctly.
I had `_tooltipUpdate` on `Item` implemented like this before,

```
_tooltipUpdate() {
    ...
}
```

but I read  that that would implement it as a prototype function instead of an instance function with the arrow operator above.

Am I using the arrow function properly? How can I change the function of the `Item` instance? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using arrow function, you are binding `this` to the calling instance of type `InventoryElement`.

If you want to call `this.element` in `Item`, you need to do

```
this.item._tooltipUpdate = function() {
    // this is now bound to Item
}.bind(this.item);
```

See [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function definition

Generally I do not think the way you would do this, is the best way.
It seems like your _tooltipUpdate is something like a handler, that enables you to react upon a change within the item. It is always better to implement some event logic and then attach listeners to it.

Also, as I see, there is just `amount` that is changing. So why not just have a method within `Item` that says `setAmount`. That would be much cleaner and easier to implement.

Comment: `amount` is not associated with `Item`, but with `InventoryElement`. I was trying to still show it on `Item`'s tooltip though, maybe that's not possible.

Comment: I know. But you are setting amount as attribute to Item.element. So why dont you associate it with Item, when the elements reacts to it?

Comment: Actually yes, I think that would be way easier and avoid the whole headache with the calling contexts and function binding and such. Thanks!